# How to create a bootstrap list group with two arrays?

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

I'm currently creating a dashboard and I want to create a "Bootstrap List Group" which should show a list of friends of the current dashboard.

I have given to arrays like this:

- friendsID[id1, id2, id3]
- friendsName[name1, name2, name3]

I want to create a method in javascript so that the result looks like this.

```
<div class="list-group">
  <a href="/dashboard/id1" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">name1</a>
  <a href="/dashboard/id2" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">name2</a>
  <a href="/dashboard/id3" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">name3</a>
</div>
```

Would love to here how you would manage this because I am a little bit desperate and have no clue how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here You can use *document.write()* to solve the problem it is used when the path for the html is not needed

```js
var friendsID = ['id1','id2','id3'];
var i=0;
var friendName = ['name1','name2','name3'];
console.log(friendName[2]);
idplace();
function idplace(){
    for(i=0;i<friendsID.length;i++)
    {
        document.write("<a href='/dashboard/"+friendsID[i]+"' class='list-group-item list-group-item-action'>"+friendName[i]+"</a><br>")
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    
    <script src="./java.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Or You can Use *Innerhtml* in this the path inside which div the html must be kept is determined by the programmer.

```js
var friendsID = ['id1','id2','id3'];
var i=0;
var statement =[0,0,0];
var friendName = ['name1','name2','name3'];
console.log(friendName[2]);
idplace();
function idplace(){
    for(i=0;i<friendsID.length;i++)
    {
        statement[i]="<a href='google.com/"+friendsID[i]+"'>"+friendName[i]+"</a><br>";
        console.log(statement[i]);
        document.getElementById("hello").innerHTML+=statement[i];
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="hello"></div>
    <script src="./java.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

```js
const friendsID = ["id1", "id2", "id3"]
const friendsName = ["name1", "name2", "name3"]
let i = 0;
for (i = 0; i < friendsID.length; i++) {
  let list = '<a href="/dashboard/' + friendsID[i] + '" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">' + friendsName[i] + "</a>"
  $(".list-group").append(list)
}
```

```html
<div class="list-group">
</div>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

check this out
https://jsfiddle.net/cloud_zero/hacLpe3g/4/

```
var arry1 = ["name1", "name2", "name3"];
var arry2 = ["id1", "id2", "id3"];

// merging two array
var result = arry1.reduce(function(acc, cur, index) {
    return Object.assign(acc, { [arry2[index]]: cur })
}, {})

// generating links
var text = Object.keys(result).map(function(key) {
    return `<a href="/dashboard/${ key }" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">${ result[key] }</a>`;
});

// finally adding to dom
document.querySelector('.list-group').innerHTML = text.join('');
```

1. first i merged two array to object (result)
2. then i generate links from the result
3. lastly linked added to DOM

Answer (score 0):

First of all thank you for your great solutions!
I also tried my best and came up with this here.

```js
var friendsIDs = ["id1", "id2", "id3"];
var friendsNames = ["name1", "name2", "name3"];
var friendLinks = [];

for (i=0; i < friendsIDs.length; i++){
  friendLinks.push("<a href=/dashboard/" + friendsIDs[i] + " class=\'list-group item list-group-item-action\' >" + friendsNames[i] + "</a>")
}
                 
//Create HTML Element for the Company Relations
var linkTarget = document.getElementById('linkTarget');
        
for(i=0; i < friendLinks.length; i++){
  linkTarget.innerHTML += friendLinks[i];
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="list-group" id="linkTarget"></div>
```